# Why does the beam splitter create superposition?

Tags: superposition, structural-beam

Why does the beam splitter create superposition ? Ok, in a double slit you have 2 holes in a wall, and thus there are 2 ways through which the particle to go. But in a beam splitter where are those 2 holes ? So my question is: at the molecular/atomic level, what is there in the beam splitter that makes it act as 2 holes in order for the particle to have 2 paths to go through and thus to enter superposition ?

Comment: Is your question ‘How does a beam splitter work?’?

Comment: Sure, but at the atomic level, not at the level "there are 2 different materials and there are 2 diffraction indexes, etc.". I want to know what makes the photon see 2 paths. What is it about the arrangements of atoms in the beam splitter that makes the photon think there are 2 paths to take ? Why not 20 paths ?

Comment: Note that the wavelength of light in such devices is very much larger than the interatomic distances. The collective coherent linear response of the atoms is crucial to the device. The coherence limits the number of lightbeam paths to two.

Comment: Why ? How ? What is the "coherent linear response" that makes it be seen by the photon as a hole ?

Comment: A hole? A beam splitter does not act as a hole.

Comment: A beam splitter is an essential part of most interferometers, but on its own it does not 'create superposition'.

Answer (score 1):

Beam splitters crucially have an (internal) interface between the materials with 2 diffraction indices. (Although depending on the beam splitter it can be the same material ordered differently, but that is not relevant to the point)
It is this interface that provides the differentiation of the 2 paths, either reflected or transmitted trough this interface. So in the analogy of holes you can think of there being 2 holes a reflection and transmission hole.

But more generally I would not try to think about superposition as fundamentally having to come from multiple holes or paths. But more akin to comming from a combination of multiple states, which can be the result of multiple paths but don't have to be.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about different paths to take, but there are always different paths! From the moment when the input state is created (probably an electron wave or light wave coming from some atom) it can take different paths.

That's because we describe space by quantum fields, having a degree of freedom at every point in space, with interaction between the neighboring points (if it is a *local* quantum field, but that's the case in the standard model of physics). So from the start we know that states in QM can spread out. The question for the beam splitter, or also the double slit experiment setup and in fact for all experiments, is more why we observe only *certain* kinds of output. You ask why there are two possible outputs for the splitter, but note that also without a splitter the wave will spread out over many points in space, so there is always splitting going on.

Why we observe only certain outcomes is then fundamentally determined by: 1) the locality of the interaction together with the limiting speed $c$, so FTL is excluded, and 2) the existence of "pointer states" that are robust against decoherence so at the macroscopic level they become the ones we can expect to see. (Possibly this is beside the point of your question, and you only want to know "how does this specific beam splitter make the quantum fields evolve in time", but then you are just asking how a beam splitter works. Anyhow, the fact that there are different paths should not be surprising, there always are!)